# UIWebView over TabBar

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, tabbar

I have a Tabbar application with a navigation controller (classic).

At some point when a url is selected a WebView controller is displayed with the appropriate url address.

I want to be able to use the tabbar area placing the webview over it. I tried
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:TRUE];

but this just makes the tabbar white.

How can i do this?

Teo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`. Then when you push the view onto the navigation stack, the bottom bar (tab bar) will be hidden.

If you want to hide the tab bar from within the view itself, afaik the only way is to hide it by either using `.hidden = YES` or changing the frame. Then you need to change the frame (more specifically the height) of the view to fill the empty space.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the height will not do anything because the tab bar is still sitting on top of the `UIView` which is holding the `UIWebView`. You need to do something to this extent:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:webView];
```

The only issue I am having now is that the `webView` is being pulled behind the `UIView` that is holding it. : (

I guess you can put an `IBOutlet` hook in there and perform a `sendToBack` on the `UIView` but I am going to keep searching for a better solution.